# Should I place gulp modules in devDependencies when deploying on Openshift?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, gulp, openshift

I have a build process which compiles Sass, minifies Javascripts and process templates in the deployment hook of openshift.

Should I put those gulp modules inside `devDependencies` like we all do, or they actually need to be `dependencies` when openshift clone the git repo, and `npm i` with production config?

Answer (score 0):

Any dependencies that are required at runtime by the Node.js process that runs your application should be in "dependencies". Otherwise they may not be installed when OpenShift deploys your app.

Any that are only required during development (that you invoke manually) go in "devDependencies". I'm not saying this is always correct, but it's the most simple way to put it.

Comment: Fact is those modules are only required in build process, not runtime. So this question is very OpenShift specific, that what environment it uses in deployment hooks. Or is it configurable somewhere?

Comment: If they're only required in the build process then they're devDependencies. This doesn't seem OpenShift specific, rather it's NPM behaviour. npm install on most services is run as npm install --production which means the install will ignore "devDependecies" and just install "dependencies". You may simply need to do npm install yourself in the hook to ensure the devDependencies are installed.